# Measurable function that's defined almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

If $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a complete measure space, and $f$ is a function that is defined almost everywhere, can I use the language that **$f$ is measurable**?  What does it mean for this function that is defined everywhere except on a set of measure $0$ to be measurable?  Does it just mean that it has a measurable extension?

Comment: There are lots of helpful answers under "related" e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344791/counterexample-for-a-non-measurable-function,  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81884/measurable-with-respect-to-completion-vs-equals-a-measurable-function-almost?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are equivalence:

- $f$ have a measurable extension.
- Preimage of any Borel set is measurable.
- $f$ is measurable on the measure subspace containing the domain of $f$.

All of them can be proved by remembering that the domain of $f$ is a measurable set. And fill the part outside the domain with $0$ to obtain an extension.